# jquery mouseover and mouseout using ID numbers

Tags: jquery

i have written a code and its perfectly works. I have used variable (var num = this.id.match(/\d+/);) multiple times and need to know how to put it in function and call this function throughout my code.

```
     $('#nav-menu1, #nav-menu2, #nav-menu3, .filter-menu').hide();

   $(".mainbutton").mouseover(function() {

    var num = this.id.match(/\d+/);

    if (!$("#nav-menu" + num).hasClass('active')) {
        $("#nav-menu" + num).stop().slideDown();
        $("#nav-menu" + num).addClass('active');
    }

}).mouseleave(function() {

    var num = this.id.match(/\d+/);

    $("#nav-menu" + num).removeClass('active');
    $("#nav-menu" + num).slideUp("fast");
});

$('.nav-menu').mouseover(function() {

    var num = this.id.match(/\d+/);
    $("#mainButton" + num).addClass('altbg');
    $(this).stop();

}).mouseleave(function() {

    var num = this.id.match(/\d+/);
    $("#mainButton" + num).removeClass('altbg');
    $(this).slideUp("fast");

}).click(function() {

    var num = this.id.match(/\d+/);
    $(this).slideUp("fast");
    $("#mainButton" + num).removeClass('altbg');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

`.match()` returns an array. The match for the whole regexp is the first element of the array, and matches for capture groups are the remaining elements. So you need to subscript it to get the match you want:

```
var num = this.id.match(/\d+/)[0];
```

You could do this in a function:

```
function get_id_num(elem) {
    return elem.id.match(/\d+/)[0];
}
```

Then all your event handlers can do:

```
var num = get_id_num(this);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I need to know how can i declare this variable only once and call this variable multiple times. Please see i used var num multiple times.

Comment: You can't declare it once. It has to be set in each event handler.